# delimiters and csv files python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a csv file where I insert a list (['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']) and it puts each item of the list into a single cell, instead of having 5 different cells each with a letter in it.

Here's my code:

```
output_file = open('output_results.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ',', dialect = 'excel')
writer.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

instead of printing out each letter in one cell, it prints out A,B,C,D,E all in one cell. It seems that the delimiter is not being used correctly? I was hoping to have the comma be the one that separated each letter into a cell.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I'm viewing the resulting CSV file in Microsoft Excel and I'm using Python 2.7.8

Comment: "All in one cell"?  How are you viewing the resulting csv file?  In Excel?  In a text editor?  Also, Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The posted code writes `A,B,C,D,E\r\n`, which looks right. Looks like a problem with Excel importing that.

Comment: How are you getting the csv file into excel.  Through data import or through Excel's open dialog or through double-clicking the csv in windows explorer?  If you are using data import you need to tell Excel explicitly what delimiter you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots type of cvs notation. One of them is use `,` and other is use `;` to separete columns. Tou can find more information following page. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example

Comment: @jasonadams:  Is your Excel set up to interpret a comma as a decimal seperator (where pi = 3,1459)?

Comment: Hi, steven you are right. I change my answer. Is it ok?

Comment: @stevenRumbalski, it seems like mine doesn't accept delimiter = ','. the semicolon worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use `'\t'` as delimiter - programs like excel will recognize it.

Comment: -1.  Excel understands comma delimited files just fine.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: @Cassum, I tried your way, all it did was to get rid of the commas, but I still cannot get them to show up in five different cells.